# keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect problem

Tags: flutter, keystore

I want to reference the keystore from the app.I create key.properties file and write `storePassword=qwertyuiop keyPassword=qwertyuiop keyAlias=upload storeFile=/Users/faridahmadov/flutter-projects/flutter_emiland/android/app/upload-keystore.jks`

them  inside of this file.

then I run this command in order to create keystore.jks
I get this error everytime.

`faridahmadov@Farids-MacBook-Air flutter_emiland %   keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA 
-keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload

Enter keystore password:
keytool error: java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
java.io.IOException: keystore password was incorrect
at java.base/sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2147)
at java.base/sun.security.util.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:226)
at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1502)
at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.doCommands(Main.java:1103)
at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.run(Main.java:420)
at java.base/sun.security.tools.keytool.Main.main(Main.java:413)
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: failed to decrypt safe contents entry: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
... 6 more`

I checked Java firstly to know if it is downloaded or not.

```
faridahmadov@Farids-MacBook-Air ~ % java -version
java version "19.0.2" 2023-01-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-44)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-44, mixed mode, sharing)
```

here it is terminal output.
I am sure I enter password correctly.What can be the problem?

for one time I entered password 'android',console admited this command.But keystore.jks file was not been generated.